# VBA errors with dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

I am a beginner in VBA. I am trying to write a macro that checks if there is any missing data in several files. If data is missing, it would add the name of the file to an array, and at the end it would give the list of files with incomplete data.

I need to have a variable array, but whatever I do to fix it, I keep getting errors. See the code below. Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

```
Sub Macro()

Dim Path1 As String
Dim Path2 As String
Dim Path3 As String
Dim Path4-5-6 As String
Dim FileName_1 As String
Dim FileName_2 As String
Dim FileName_3 As String
Dim FileName_4 As String
Dim FileName_5 As String
Dim FileName_6 As String
Dim W As Long
Dim Missing As Boolean
Dim len_ListMissing As Long
Dim Found As Boolean
Dim k As Variant
Dim dict
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim n As Integer, i As Variant
ReDim ListMissing(n)

Path1 = "https://_path1_"
Path2 = "https://_path2_"
Path3 = "https://_path3_"
Path4-5-6 = "https://_path4-5-6_"
FileName_1 = "file1.xlsx"
FileName_2 = " file2.xlsx"
FileName_3 = " file3.xlsx"
FileName_4 = " file4.xlsx"
FileName_5 = " file5.xlsx"
FileName_6 = " file6.xlsx"

W = Workbooks("_currentfile_.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value
dict.Add Path1 & FileName_1, FileName_1
dict.Add Path2 & FileName_2, FileName_2
dict.Add Path3 & FileName_3, FileName_3
dict.Add Path4-5-6 & FileName_4, FileName_4
dict.Add Path4-5-6 & FileName_5, FileName_5
dict.Add Path4-5-6 & FileName_6, FileName_6

ListMissing(0) = "test"

For Each k In dict.keys
Workbooks.Open (k)
    If Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “X”).Value = "" Or Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “X”).Value = "0" Or Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “Y”).Value = "" Or Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “Y”).Value = "0" Or Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “Z”).Value = "" Or Workbooks(dict(k)).Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “Z”).Value = "0" Then
        Missing = True
    Else
        Missing = False
    End If
    
    n = 0
    If Missing = True Then
        For Each i In ListMissing
            If i = dict(k) Then
                Found = True
            Else
                Found = False
            End If
                
            If Found = False Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve ListMissing(1 To n)
                ListMissing(n) = dict(k)
            Else

            End If

        Next i
    End If
Workbooks(dict(k)).Close SaveChanges:=False
Next

len_ListMissing = UBound(ListMissing) - LBound(ListMissing) + 1
If len_ListMissing = 1 Then
    MsgBox "Data is complete."
Else
    MsgBox "Data is incomplete in the below files:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ListMissing(i)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get an error? Is the file path correct, or is there a file seperator missing? What is the purpose of the dictonary, you are only using the keys and not the values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, show what line arises the error when debugging

Comment: The purpose of the dictionary is to combine values to get the right paths. The macro works perfectly fine if there is no data missing.
If there is data missing I get the following error: "Run time error 10: this array is fixed or temporarily locked" This is the line in the code causing issue:
`ReDim Preserve ListMissing(1 To n)`

Comment: The array is maybe locked because you use an element `i` in this `for each`. If you would asign the open workbench to an object/variable, you could use the dictonary to store the missing status

Comment: I am sorry I am just beginning in VBA and coding, I do not quite understand what you mean, I still do not know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Here a example to use the dictonary to store the `missing status` (code not testet)

```vb
dict.Add sFullPath1, true
dict.Add sFullPath2, true

for each k in dict
   set wbToCheck = Workbooks.Open(k)
   if wbToCheck.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(W + 20, “X”).Value = "" then 'only one condition in this example
     dict(k)= true
   else
     dict(k) = false
   end if
   wbToCheck.Close SaveChanges:=False
next
```

so you would not need this additional array.

Comment: Can I keep the dictionary as is and add an array instead? The path is made of 2 parts hence the need to have a dictionary. Having the full path in th ekey and a boolean value in the item would complicate things for me, because I need the macro to return the list of files having missing data (this is why I need to add files with missing data in the array).

Comment: You don't need a dictionary for storing the filenames, therefore you could use an array or a collection. On your array _ListMissing_ you can add the filenames without checking if there already exist (in the dictionary the (fullpath) filenames are unique).

Comment: Hi Shrotter, I tried doing so but I am stuck with an error 10 "This array is fixed or temporary locked" I tried:
`Dim ListMissing() As String`
`ReDim Preserve ListMissing(1 To 6)`
     [some code]
`If Found = False Then`
`ReDim Preserve ListMissing(1 To UBound(ListMissing) + 1)`
`ListMissing(UBound(ListMissing)) = dict(k)`

It's the second line ReDim Preserve that causes issues.

Comment: How can I fix the run-time error 10 "This array is fixed or temporary locked"?

Comment: Do you try to redim during looping the array? Try if without that _for each_ and redim the array.